# Symfony2 multiple kernels for different purposes?

Tags: rest, symfony

I just wanted to ask a question here, I'm building an application using Symfony2 and it will likely require REST API at some point.

I don't want to wait for that point to rebuild the app later, so I decided to work on an appropriate structure / architecture now.

So, my question is: Is it a good practice to have multiple kernels? The reason for that is mainly performance considerations of loading bundles like Twig and several others not really required by an API.

I would really appreciate if you could point me to some resources on that, no matter what the answer is!

@EDIT

To clarify what I'd like to do:

- have one kernel called WebKernel prepared for full HTML responses
- have another kernel called ApiKernel stripped from bundles not needed for API (twig, etc.)
- have two front controllers [web.php and api.php] both utilizing their respective kernel
- have web server configured to redirect to api.php front controller on /api/* or using api subdomain

Is it wise? I'm also aware I will need to have separate environment-like (I guess having separate environments will do) configuration files to account for missing bundles in ApiKernel.

Comment: Take a look at [this presentation](https://speakerdeck.com/odolbeau/symfony-at-blablacar) (slide 23) about the problem with this approach

Comment: And some more useful information regarding having two applications in one, can be found in here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/symfony-devs/yneojUuFiqw/sZ8BZrzFLbwJ

Comment: Have you considered still having one kernel but registering only bundles you need for current request at `registerBundles` method?

Comment: @AndreyMischenko I did think of that, but having separate kernels seem cleaner approach, because otherwise I will have to decide on environment inside the front controller instead (based on some header set by web server or request path)

Comment: official pull-request in process about that https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/pull/6840

Comment: @Yonel this is the approach I wanted to use! Thank you very much, for me that's enough confirmation I can simply go that way. Using the same approach for micro-services is a great addition. If you can make it an answer I'll mark it as answered!